# How to change the table name for the revision table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, revisionable

How to change the table name for the revision table by default it is `'revisions';`
But I want it to something like `page_revisions` cause there are many tables with different prefixes. So, I just need how to change the name via config in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table name is not configurable by the package.

If you want to do this, you will need to:

- Fork the package
- Update your composer.json to look at your forked package,
- Update the `$table` property in the `Venturecraft\Revisionable\Revision` model in your fork to use the `page_revisions` table, and
- Update the migration in your fork to create the `page_revisions` table.

However, once you fork the package, you will now be responsible for keeping it up to date with the original package (if you care about any updates).

Answer (score 0):

just specify a variable named $table in your revision model.

```
protected $table = 'page_revisions';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think forking is the right way. There's a way without forking, probably what Gokigooooks meant, but there are a few more steps necessary.

Make sure you've published the configuration (`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableServiceProvider"` ).

Next, create a modal `Revision` in your app folder with the following content:

```php
<?php
namespace App;

class Revision extends \Venturecraft\Revisionable\Revision
{
    public $table = 'page_revisions';
}
```

Next, open the config file (`config/revisionable.php`) and change the model class:

```php
<?php
return [
    'model' => App\Revision::class,
];
```

That way you only override the revision class and don't have to manage your own fork.